# Flooring layout software

Tags: graphic-design, visual-design, floor-plan

I'm trying to come up with a flooring layout for a corridor with Granite of different colours and specifically of a specific pattern, such as the one below.

[image: Granite flooring pattern]

Given a corridor dimension, I need to visualise how it would appear and what dimensions of these granites and what quantity I'd need. - And a few options of these different sizes.

I'm aware that building architects use Autocad and other such software for that purpose. I'm interested to know how I can use any accessible software mostly those used for web design, such as Sketch, Photoshop or any other online design software with layout definitions and patterns for the purpose above.

In the least, at least I want something to do the following to scale, which I was thinking up using a pen and paper.

[image: Hand-drawn layout sketch]

What options do I have?

Comment: Perhaps you need to give a more complex example which can't be done in a generic spreadsheet application? (online or otherwise) http://i.stack.imgur.com/U2fgF.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some thought, I ended up creating a full complex pattern using an Excel spreadsheet.

[image]

I feel tremendously badass for having accomplished a task I thought I'd have depend on some CAD software and personnel who can work with it.

For anybody else that ever comes across this need and is looking for a solution, here is the spreadsheet: http://files.lakshmanprasad.com/flooring-pattern.xlsx

Comment: So you really copy & pasted all those tiles and positioned them manually in Excel? Not sure if that's a good, reusable recommendation. I'm glad you solved the problem and I'm sad that there's no better solution at the time. Thanks for being brave and posting it here. Finally a +/- 0 from my side.

Comment: Yea, of course copy pasted. But I'm pretty good in navigating with excel with Cmd+down, cmd+up and pasting at once.

Comment: Once I figured out how this could be achieved, it took no longer time than what it would have even with a CAD tool for doing the same. I did crash Excel Mac 2016 about 10 times in this process though. - I also understood the reasons for the crash and tried to avoid those situations.